# Is every increasing function a one-to-one function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Are  all the increasing functions as one-to-one functions? Can anyone provide a proof for that or at least give some examples?

Comment: You need _strictly_ increasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every increasing function is not indeed one-one.

Let, $$x_1>x_2$$

$$f(x_1)\geq f(x_2)$$

This will remain stagnant from $x_1$ to $x_2$, all the values between $x_1$ and $x_2$ will have same value.

**All strictly increasing function are one-one.**

$$x_1>x_2$$

$$f(x_1)> f(x_2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if $x \ne y$, say $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$ so $f(x) \ne f(y)$ and this is it.